# Matlab programming - Feedback error

Tags: matlab, sorting, feedback

I am trying out the questions in programming assignment of Coursera course on Matlab programming as an exercise. This is my Question:

> Write a function called sort3 that takes three scalar arguments. It uses if-statements, possibly nested, to
>   return the three values of these arguments in a single row-vector in increasing order (or more precisely,
>   non-decreasing order), i.e., element one of the output vector equals the smallest input argument and
>   element three of the output vector equals the largest input argument.

Here is my code:

```
function sv = sort3(x,y,z)

if nargin < 3
    error('must have at least three input argument');
else
    if ~isscalar(x) || x ~= fix(x)
        error('x needs to be a scalar');
    end
    if ~isscalar(y) || y ~= fix(y)
        error('y needs to be a scalar');
    end
    if ~isscalar(z) || z ~= fix(z)
        error('z needs to be a scalar');
    end
end

a=x;
b=y;
c=z;

if  a >= b
    t=a;
    a=b;
    b=t;
end
if b >= c
    t=b;
    b=c;
    c=t;
end
if a >= b
    t=a;
    a=b;
    b=t;
end

if nargout == 1
    sv=[a b c];
end
```

I got the below result on Matlab.

```
Problem 3 (sort3):
Feedback: Your program made an error for argument(s) -1.3719900292403, -0.639443998445333, 1.04704952581735
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: For me it works for integer valued numbers (including doubles where the decimal part is zero). The addition `x ~= fix(x)` throws an **"x needs to be a scalar"** error for decimal numbers though, so you should consider removing it (for all variables of course).

Answer (score 0):

When you compare x with fix(x) your program moves to the command error that you have written.
When you pass to your function a decimal number, obviously x is always not equal to fix(x) and then your function will always end with an error.
If you want to work only with scalars or integers, you can think to apply function fix to your input before to start with your algorithm.